# sendmessage only works with one page

Tags: php, fancybox, sendmessage

I have a kind of a quiz running soon, where the answers are shown and should be submitted via email. 
The script uses a sendmessage.php which runs fine for "answer one". All other answers, despite the pages being absolutely equal (except for the text) dont.

This is the correct page "one":

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
  <script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
</head>

<body>
<H2><br />
</H2>
<div id="wrapper">
  <d>Der größte Fan</d><br> 
  <br>

<p>Du liebst alles, was mit Schönheit zu tun hat! 
Warum teilst du nicht deine Leidenschaft für Mary Kay® Produkte mit deiner Familie und deinen     Freunden? 
Du kannst nicht verbergen, wie du dich damit fühlst – gepflegt, selbstbewusst und schön!<br>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">

  Schick uns dein Ergebnis, und erhalte die Einladung zur Facebook-Gruppe!</p>

    <p><a class="modalbox" href="#inline">Ergebnis ans Mary Kay<sup>&reg;</sup> Büro schicken</a>    </p>
</div>

<!-- hidden inline form -->
<div id="inline">
    <h2>Schick uns dein Ergebnis</h2>

    <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="cons">Deine Consultantnummer</label>
        <input type="cons" id="cons" name="cons" maxlength="8" class="txt"><br>
        <label for="name">Dein     Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&    nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="name" id="name" name="name" class="txt"><br>
        <label for="email">Deine     Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
        <br>
        <label for="msg">Mein Ergebnis lautet:</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea" readonly>Der größte Fan. Du liebst alles,     was mit Schönheit zu tun hat! 
Warum teilst du nicht deine Leidenschaft für Mary Kay® Produkte mit deiner Familie und deinen     Freunden? 
Du kannst nicht verbergen, wie du dich damit fühlst – gepflegt, selbstbewusst und schön!     </textarea>

        <button id="send">Email abschicken</button>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- basic fancybox setup -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateEmail(email) { 
        var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]    {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return reg.test(email);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modalbox").fancybox();
        $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


        $("#send").on("click", function(){
            var emailval  = $("#email").val();
            var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
            var msglen    = msgval.length;
            var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

            if(mailvalid == false) {
                $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(mailvalid == true){
                $("#email").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(msglen < 4) {
                $("#msg").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(msglen >= 4){
                $("#msg").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
                // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
                // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
                $("#send").replaceWith("<em>wird verschickt...</em>");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'sendmessage.php',
                    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {
                            $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<p><strong>Super! Deine Ergebnisse sind zu uns     unterwegs! Vielen Dank :)</strong></p>");
                                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 5000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The sendmesaage is as follows:

```
<?php
$sendto   = "me@myaddress.com";
$username = $_POST['name'];
$usercons = $_POST['cons'];
$usermail = $_POST['email'];
$fromfield = "online_formular@myaddress.com";
$content  = nl2br($_POST['msg']);

$subject  = "Ein Quiz wurde ausgefüllt";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($fromfield) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Ein Quiz wurde ausgefüllt</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Absender:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Cons.-Nr.:</strong> ".$usercons."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Email:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Nachricht:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";


if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

?>
```

That combination works - all files in the same directory. 
When I use the second answer (two.html) - it doesnt do anything... it states that is was sent, but it will never arrive.

Two:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
</head>

<body>
<H2><br />
</H2>
<div id="wrapper">
  <d>Die Netzwerkerin</d><br> 
  <br>

<p>
Deine Freunde sind dir am wichtigsten. Deshalb ist für dich ein Geschäft perfekt, das es dir ermöglicht, mehr Zeit mit deinen Freundinnen zu verbringen und gleichzeitig neue Freundschaften aufzubauen. 
<br>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">

  Schick uns dein Ergebnis, und erhalte die Einladung zur Facebook-Gruppe!</p>

    <p><a class="modalbox" href="#inline">Ergebnis ans Mary Kay<sup>&reg;</sup> Büro schicken</a></p>
</div>

<!-- hidden inline form -->
<div id="inline">
    <h2>Schick uns dein Ergebnis</h2>

    <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="cons">Deine Consultantnummer</label>
        <input type="cons" id="cons" name="cons" maxlength="8" class="txt"><br>
        <label for="name">Dein Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="name" id="name" name="name" class="txt"><br>
        <label for="email">Deine Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
        <br>
        <label for="msg">Mein Ergebnis lautet:</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea" readonly>Die Netzwerkerin. Deine Freunde sind dir am wichtigsten. Deshalb ist für dich ein Geschäft perfekt, das es dir ermöglicht, mehr Zeit mit deinen Freundinnen zu verbringen und gleichzeitig neue Freundschaften aufzubauen.</textarea>

        <button id="send">Email abschicken</button>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- basic fancybox setup -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateEmail(email) { 
        var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return reg.test(email);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modalbox").fancybox();
        $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


        $("#send").on("click", function(){
            var emailval  = $("#email").val();
            var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
            var msglen    = msgval.length;
            var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

            if(mailvalid == false) {
                $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(mailvalid == true){
                $("#email").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(msglen < 4) {
                $("#msg").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(msglen >= 4){
                $("#msg").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
                // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
                // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
                $("#send").replaceWith("<em>wird verschickt...</em>");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'sendmessage.php',
                    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {
                            $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<p><strong>Super! Deine Ergebnisse sind zu uns unterwegs! Vielen Dank :)</strong></p>");
                                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 5000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has any suggestions, that would be awesome!
Thanks in advance, 
Dimitri

Comment: Maybe you should start by removing the `@` in front of the `mail` function so you could possibly see what is going wrong. What happens if you go directly to your sendmessage.php file?

Comment: Removing the "@" didnt make a change. It still would say that the form is being sent.
When calling the sendmessage directly it only gives "true" on the page. 

Page one still works with that change.

Comment: have you tried `cache: false` in your ajax functions?

Comment: where would I most likely put that?
Sorry for the late reply, I was out on vacation!

Comment: Update: found out where, tried it - no change.